# Подключение пользовательской библиотеки на Си в проект на Mono

Tags: c#, linux, .net, mono

Возникла проблема. Была пользовательская библиотека написанная на Си, которую благополучно собрали и установили автосборщиком. Библиотека установилась в директорию /usr/local/lib. По мануалу разработчика библиотеки проделано следующее:

> echo /usr/local/lib/ > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/usr.conf
>   ldconfig -v

После чего вывелся список и я увидел что для библиотеки создана ссылка:

> /usr/local/lib:
>   libiocapi.so.0 -> libiocapi.so.0.1.0

[image: либы]

Далее в проекте на C# сделано следующее:

```
[DllImport("libiocapi.so.0", EntryPoint = "iocApiOpenIoCluster")]
    public static extern int IocApiOpenIoCluster(short ioType, short cluster);

    private static void OpenCluster(IoTypes ioType, cluster)
    {
        var status = IocApiOpenIoCluster((short) ioType, cluster);

        CheckStatus(status);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OpenCluster(IoTypes.Bus)
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

При запуске приложение упало с ошибкой System.DllNotFoundException

Запустил приложение с режиме Mono Debug:

> MONO_LOG_LEVEL="debug" MONO_LOG_MASK="dll" mono MyApp.exe

Отладчик написал, что не может найти библиотеку libiocapi.so.0 в папке с проектом. Далее я отредактировал файл config Mono etc/mono/config, добавил следующую строчку и сохранился:

```
 <dllmap dll="libiocapi0" target="libiocapi.so.0" os="!windows"/>
```

Эти действия не привели ни к чему новому. 
На Си в блокноте было написано тестовое приложение и подключены заголовочные файлы из библиотеки (привожу частичный код):

```
   #include "iocapi.h"

   void demo(void) {
    /* ... OPEN Device to Read/Write .........................*/
     status = iocApiOpenIoCluster(IOCAPI_DI,cluster);
      if (status != 0)
       {
          perror("error");
          printf ("OPEN error for /dev/d1_%d\n", cluster);
       }
   }


   int main(void)
   {
      demo();
      return 0;
   }
```

Оно сразу же заработало (видимо глобальная ссылка на библиотеку создалась верно).

На данный момент проблема решена в "лоб" - библиотека libiocapi.so.0 и  libiocapi.so.0.1.0 (прошу простить, если путаю понятия, я не специалист в данной ОС) просто скопированы в директорию, где находится исполняемая программа написанная на C#. Хотелось бы понять, как правильно добавить путь к динамическим библиотекам в ОС Linux для работы на C# в Mono Runtime.

Comment: [Linux Shared Library Search Path](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/#linux-shared-library-search-path). Это не ответ, это откуда начать смотреть. А где закончить, пока неясно.

Comment: Благодарю за ваш ответ! Ссылка полезная. Разбираюсь дальше.

Comment: Не знаю что произошло, но все заработало само собой... Может быть мапинг не сразу прошел.